# Equivalent python hmac method in c#

Tags: python, c#

I'm trying to pair my Philips TV in a .NET program i am wrting.

I found this awessome Python library nammed [pylips](https://github.com/eslavnov/pylips) and I am using it as a reference, but having a hard time with the signature method.

I dont know python, and have tried mutiple solution to reproduce same signature in c#

```
auth["auth_signature"] = self.create_signature(b64decode(secret_key), str(auth_Timestamp).encode() + str(pin).encode())
      
def create_signature(self, secret_key, to_sign):
sign = HMAC.new(secret_key, to_sign, SHA)
return str(b64encode(sign.hexdigest().encode()))
```

If i run "create_signature" in python with following arguments

```
to_sign= 1400493467    
secret_key = JCqdN5AcnAHgJYseUn7ER5k3qgtemfUvMRghQpTfTZq7Cvv8EPQPqfz6dDxPQPSu4gKFPWkJGw32zyASgJkHwCjU
```

I get this output

```
b'Y2NiNDQ4ZDcyYjg5ZmJlNzg1MWNiYjIyYzEwOGNhMTJmNWZmODYwNA=='
```

Comment: Could you please explain what do you exactly want  ?

Comment: I'm trying to write an plugin to my home automation system to controll my TV, but having problem translating the signature metohod from python to c#

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I have at least a couple of questions, but I think I can show a simple answer.

- Your `to_sign` is a concatenated string of a timestamp `auth_Timestamp`
  and some `pin`.
- You have to see how this timestamp is generated (in
  my example I imply it is the Unix-Time).
- The pin - is this the
  `message` actually or some other value (in my example I imply it is
  the message)?
- Which SHA algorithm are you using (`SHA`)? Because the correct HMAC implementation depends on this (in my example I imply SHA256).

  ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int message = 1400493467;
       string secret_key = "key";

       string auth_Timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();// is this the Unix-Time
       string pin = message.ToString(); // is this the message?

       string to_sign = auth_Timestamp + pin;//str(auth_Timestamp).encode() + str(pin).encode()
       string result = create_signature(secret_key, to_sign);
       Console.WriteLine(result);
   }

   private static string create_signature(string secret_key, string to_sign)
   {
       // Which SHA are you using? SHA256 (HMACSHA256), SHA1 (HMACSHA1) or something else
       using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret_key)))
       {
           var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(to_sign));
           return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that my post could be misunderstand as i named it messsage and not "to_sign" (i have edited my post)
You ask witch SHA algorithm i use, I have tried both SHA256 as you use and SHA1 but get diffrent result than i get when running the python script